# Какой/как образ установить на Orange pi lite2?

Tags: linux, debian, arm

История у меня довольно грустная. 
Пытаю установить хоть какую-нибудь версию *unix на orange, но получается запустить только ubuntu_server Version0.9.1 с сайта http://orangepi.org/downloadresources , но он настолько кривой, что ни одни дрова поставить не удается, а моя цель это запустить камеру.
Перепробовал уже почти все доступные дистрибутивы , все они либо не стартуют (горит красная лампочка), либо не пускает по ssh. Очень хочу поставить https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-lite-2/ , но не получается(

Для записи образов использую win32 disk и balena.io/etcher/

Прошу поделиться опытом / знаниями об установки образа именно на orange pi lite 2.
Буду рад любому комментарию!

p.s подключаюсь по ssh по wi-fi , т.к не имею провода для подключения апельсинки к монитору.

Comment: консольный провод есть? usb uart добудь и станет легче копаться в этом.

Comment: Вот оно величе ARM по сравнению с x86! А по сути предыдущий комментарий верен. Хотя я думаю, что вам это не поможет. Там же сильно перепатченные ядра, а никакая не vanilla.